# How to loop through Ajax success results multidimensional

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops

I am trying to Alert out error messages received from an Ajax post.  When one error is returned, the alert message displays appropriately.  However, when more than one is returned, I get "Undefined". How can display both a single error message and a list of multiple error messages?  Thanks.

Sample results:

```
{"Status":{"Code":"400","Description":"Validation Failed. Please check your input parameters."},"Errors":[{"Code":"7106","Description":"The subscriber type is required"},{"Code":"7108","Description":"The service address house number is required"},{"Code":"7109","Description":"The service address street name is required"},{"Code":"7110","Description":"The service address city is required"},{"Code":"7111","Description":"The service address state code is required"},{"Code":"7112","Description":"The service address zip code is required"},{"Code":"7115","Description":"The LOA authorizing person is required"},{"Code":"7101","Description":"At least one number must be specified to port"}],"ProcessingStatus":"EXCEPTION","RequestedFocDate":"2022-07-07T21:15:00Z","LoaAuthorizingPerson":{},"Subscriber":{"FirstName":"Steve","LastName":"McKinnon","ServiceAddress":{"HousePrefix":{},"HouseNumber":{},"HouseSuffix":{},"StreetName":{},"City":{},"StateCode":{},"Zip":{}}},"WirelessInfo":{"AccountNumber":{},"PinNumber":{}},"BillingTelephoneNumber":{},"NewBillingTelephoneNumber":{},"ListOfPhoneNumbers":{},"Triggered":"false","TnAttributes":{}}
```

My Attempt:

```
$.each(result['Errors']['Description'], function(index, val) {
            $.each(val, function(index, val2) {
                alert(val2.Code+" : "+val2.Description);
         });
```

Comment: Make sure you return an array each time?

Comment: You're diving too deep. Iterate `result.Errors` and look at the `val.description` of each.

Answer (score 0):

You're diving too deep.

```js
$(function() {
  var results = {
    "Status": {
      "Code": "400",
      "Description": "Validation Failed. Please check your input parameters."
    },
    "Errors": [{
      "Code": "7106",
      "Description": "The subscriber type is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7108",
      "Description": "The service address house number is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7109",
      "Description": "The service address street name is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7110",
      "Description": "The service address city is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7111",
      "Description": "The service address state code is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7112",
      "Description": "The service address zip code is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7115",
      "Description": "The LOA authorizing person is required"
    }, {
      "Code": "7101",
      "Description": "At least one number must be specified to port"
    }],
    "ProcessingStatus": "EXCEPTION",
    "RequestedFocDate": "2022-07-07T21:15:00Z",
    "LoaAuthorizingPerson": {},
    "Subscriber": {
      "FirstName": "Steve",
      "LastName": "McKinnon",
      "ServiceAddress": {
        "HousePrefix": {},
        "HouseNumber": {},
        "HouseSuffix": {},
        "StreetName": {},
        "City": {},
        "StateCode": {},
        "Zip": {}
      }
    },
    "WirelessInfo": {
      "AccountNumber": {},
      "PinNumber": {}
    },
    "BillingTelephoneNumber": {},
    "NewBillingTelephoneNumber": {},
    "ListOfPhoneNumbers": {},
    "Triggered": "false",
    "TnAttributes": {}
  };

  $.each(results.Errors, function(i, error) {
    console.log(error.Code, error.Description);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`Errors` is an Array of Objects. If you want to capture `Description` for each Error, you will need to iterate the Array and capture the one Index.

Comment: @SouthpawUSMC I am glad to hear that. If you like, you can upvote the answer and when able, you can Mark it as the answer.